# 'above right=1pt and 2pt' not running

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following M(N)WE should - at least according to the fine manual - be valid code.
But instead it delivers `Package PGF Math Error: Unknow operator 'a' or 'an' (in '1pt and 2pt')`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[above right=1pt and 2pt] at (0,0) {test};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I use `tikz` 2013/12/13 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.142). Does anyone have a helpful hint?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`above right=1pt and 2pt` is supported by the `tikz` library `positioning` hence you need to put `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` in the preamble after loading `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}   %%<----------------------------
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
  \filldraw (0,0) circle(2pt) node[above right=1pt and 2pt] {test};  
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, what a shame. Yes, this comes at the beginning of this section in the manual. I should get used to get back to this beginning after having searched and found my topic. Thanks a lot for the quick answer!